# bash read of a newline, printf reports character 0

Tags: bash, shell-script, newlines, read

I use bash `printf` function to print ASCII codes of characters in an input file, but for some reason `printf` outputs ascii code 0 for `LF` characters, instead of 10. Any ideas why?

```
while IFS= read -r -n1 c
do
ch=$(LC_CTYPE=C printf "%d\n" "'$c") # convert to integer
echo "ch=$ch"
done < input_file_name
```

To be honest, I am not even sure if this is a problem with `printf` or it is the `read` function, which supplies the wrong value of LF... Are there other ways how to convert characters to ASCII using bash commands?

Comment: I assume the single - quote mark is a typo?

Comment: Where exactly do you get a 0 that you don't expect?

Comment: I can replicate this problem on centos 6.6

Comment: Single quote mark is definitely not a typo)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

first your printf function works perfectly

```
$ export c=" "
$ LC_CTYPE=C printf "%d\n" "'$c"
32
```

But running the script line with -vx on shows that the data getting to this line is wrong ( I won't paste this output )

So I figure it is the read that is wrong.  The default EOL delimiter for read is newline, so I tried altering that.  This seems to work

```
while IFS= read -d\0 -r -n1 c; do ch=$(LC_CTYPE=C printf "%d\n" "'$c") ; echo "ch=$ch"; done < input_file_name
```

Comment: sorry for the late acknowledgement of your answer. it was exactly what I needed in order to resolve the problem.

Answer (score 2):

The `read` isn't wrong but you are interpreting the results slightly wrongly.

The EOL marker is `\n`, so entering that character means that `read` has encountered a "line" that has no characters. Note that the variable `$c` doesn't contain the `\n`:

```
while IFS= read -r c
do
    test -z "$c" && echo "Zero length string" || echo "I read '$c'"
done
```

By adding `-n1` you are limiting the number of characters that can be read to just the one. Just like in the example above, the `\n` is not part of the accepted string, so `read` returns "nothing" when you enter `\n`:

```
while IFS= read -r -n1 c
do
    test -z "$c" && echo "Zero length string" || echo "I read '$c'"
done
```

The `printf` command is interesting. If you feed it a single-quote-prefixed zero length string you also get '0' out of it, so I suspect the answer here is "don't do that":

```
LC_CTYPE=C printf "%d" "'" | od -c
0000000   0
```

Comment: Your last command doesn't match the previous paragraph (a single quote is not a zero length string) and the output is not `\0` (null) but a numeric `0`.

Comment: @jlliagre re `\0` vs `0`, yes I'll fix that, and expand the other part